# How can I vet my HTML email signature code

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm new to HTML and I am designing an HTML email signature for the first time. I believe the code is properly written but I've had some issues. I attempted to get clearer images by saving each slice at twice the resolution then downsizing using HTML. However, in some email clients each image would have added padding around each image cell making the email signature look broken apart. Other browsers and clients would have images and text showing up blurry.

I gave up and stuck to the same image size and resolution in both the image size and the HTML coding which seems to work better. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    td {line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em; }
    img { display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Test Email.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="516" height="172" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    

    <td rowspan="7">
        <a href=example.com><img src="image1.jpg" width="161" height="172" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <img src="exampleimage2.jpg" width="315" height="80" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <a href=example.com><img src=image3.jpg" width="39" height="44" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="44" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <a href=example.com><img src="image4.jpg" width="39" height="43" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="36" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <a href="tel:8888888888"><img src="image5.jpg" width="111" height="30" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <a href="mailto:mail.com"><img src="image6.jpg" width="204" height="30" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="7" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <a href=example.com><img src="image7.jpg" width="39" height="43" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="23" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <a href=goo.gl/maps><img src="image8.jpg" width="315" height="38" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="20" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <a href=example.com><img src="image9.jpg" width="39" height="42" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="18" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="image10.jpg" width="315" height="24" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="24" alt=""></td>

 </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
<div style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
<style>
  hr {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #9d9d9d;
    border: none;
  }
  div {
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-left: 8px;
}
</style>
<body>
<hr>
<span style="font-size:9pt;  font-family: 'Cambria','times new roman','garamond',serif; color:#223488;">This email may contain confidential and/or proprietary information. If you are not the intended addressee or have received this e-mail in error, please inform the sender immediately and destroy this e-mail. Unauthorized copying and/or forwarding of this email is strictly prohibited.
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's something over and above all of this which is that: does it work on mobiles? Most people read emails on their phone (70-80%), so if it's 516px wide what will happen is that your email will be reduced in size to fit (you will want to fit to at least 300px, if not 280px to cover the smallest).

Otherwise, assuming the email environment you use automatically uploads the images, to remove the gaps you would use the following set of defaults (a HTML email CSS reset needs to be inline, not in `<style>`):

For `<td>` write `<td style="padding:0">`

For `<img>` write `<img style="display:block;border-width:0;">`

If you wanted something that worked on mobiles, I would go for something thinner. Then on your `<table>` use `style="min-width:200px;max-width:300px"` if you need a small measure of responsive behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Nathan. Like I said, I'm really new to HTML but let me try to see if I understand this clearly. My full width of the entire signature is 516px. Are you saying that if I use the style="min-width:200px;max-width:300px" code then my 516px image would automatically be resized to 300px on just mobile or would it be for both mobile and desktop? Also, I'm not entirely sure where I would include the <td style="padding:0"> or <img style="display:block;border-width:0;"> code. Can you help me understand that please and then I'll reupload my code to see if it's right.

Comment: Sorry for not responding, I did not get a notification. If your content, such as an image, is 516px wide, no it will not automatically resize. I was saying to reconfigure it entirely to something thinner. What I am saying about the <td> and <img> is to add those styles to every one of them, to remove the spacing.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I added something like this. <td rowspan="7" style="padding:0">
   <a href=example.com><img src="image1.png" width="161" height="172" alt=""><img style="display:block;border-width:0;"></td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="padding:0">
   <img src="image2.jpg" width="315" height="80" alt=""><img style="display:block;border-width:0;"></td>
  <td style="padding:0">>
   <a href=example.com><img src="image3.jpg" width="39" height="44" alt=""><img style="display:block;border-width:0;"></td> ...is this the right setup? It is still adding padding in Outlook for some reason. :(